# JQuery / Javascript refresh and re-trigger script in DOM

Tags: jquery, refresh

I am using a javascript file to simulate an iOS scrolling function for scrollable divs on site. The script is supposed to reset when the size of the div changes after an ajax load. This bit I cannot get to work. On normal browser the div expands as expected. On iOS the panel will not scroll at all.

The code is called iScroll http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

After an ajax load this script is triggered. It is exactly what the documentation says to do. On the load event I have created the global variables listed below.

```
function onCompletion() {
    myScroll1.refresh();
    myScroll2.refresh(); 
    myScroll3.refresh(); 
    myScroll4.refresh(); 
    myScroll5.refresh(); 
    myScroll6.refresh();
};
```

Can anyone see whats not working?

Marvellous

Comment: Can you show your markup and where `myScroll1` through `myScroll6` are defined?

Comment: Thanks for you help. Resolved problem with a timeout

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions a 0 second timeout will fix the problem. This did not do it but changing the timeout to 1000ms did. Thus the onCompletion() function should look like this.

```
function onCompletion() {

    setTimeout(function () {

        myScroll1.refresh(); myScroll2.refresh(); myScroll3.refresh(); myScroll4.refresh(); myScroll5.refresh(); myScroll6.refresh();
 }, 1000);
}
```

That is fully functional. The solution was in one of the iScroll demos and is completely contrary to the documentation.